# Internet connection problems after installation of Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

After installing Ubuntu from a live USB, I have been having problems with connecting to the internet ever since Ubuntu began to install. The first known time an issue occurred to me was during the installation process. During Ubuntu was first installing, it was having trouble downloading language packs and other packages. It took about 45 minutes each time it had to download packages (2 times).

After the installation, I could not search on Firefox, although the little connection symbol on the top right was telling me that I was connected. After a little while, I was able to search on Google, but only for a minute. It should be noted that the Ubuntu Software Center was having troubles connecting as well.

I currently am using Windows 8 with no internet connection problems and am Dual-Booting Ubuntu with it. I am completely new to Ubuntu, so please be simple with your answers.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The internet connection problems may be due to your wireless card being incompatible with the default open source drivers.

Can you post the output when the following is entered in a terminal?

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

In case you are using a Broadcom (BCMxxxx) wireless card, head over to 'Additional Drivers' and select the available proprietary driver (bcmwl-kernel-source) and you are good to go.